# correctly display an image on a button using css (cross-browser)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a button so that it would have an image on it:

my html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn"> 
<span></span>
</button>
```

my css:

```
.btn
{
    margin-right: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    padding: 0;
}

.btn span
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;    
    width: 16px; 
    height: 18px; 
    background-image: url(updown.png);    
    background-position: -1px -3px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

with this css it looks centered in mozilla but a bit higher in chrome and and a bit more to the left top corner in IE, anybody knows how to do this correctly, so that it would look the same in all browsers?

Comment: This is a weird way to do it, why not just add CSS bg-image to the button?

Comment: Are you ok with css hacks? So you can add small tweaks for those brosers.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks I looked at jQuery UI demos and saw they do it this way

Comment: Fair enough, then _they_ did it a weird way. I'd get rid of the span and just add the styles to the button element.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the button a relative possition and the span an absolute one?

(This would be a comment, but I'm not allowed to comment on things. Sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Make it `.btn position:relative` and `span position:absolute`